# how to modify the title template jrxml

Tags: dynamic-jasper

I created a template file with ireport 4.0.2 and set the template file in code :

`drb.setTemplateFile("report1.jrxml");`

However, I cant set the title of the template when I do this:

```
drb.setTitle("Comptes du client")    //defines the title of the report
.setSubtitle("Détails Compte ")
```

the second problem that when i add a `GlobalFooterVariable(columnSolde, DJCalculation.SUM)`,it works but I have a label "GLOBAL" that appear in the left

how can i fix this ? any answer thanks

You can find the report how it look on this url

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h0Vq.png

Answer (score 0):

Set
`drb.setGrandTotalLegend("Grand Total ")
drb.setGrandTotalLegendStyle(footerStyle)`

and set the style for footer text as:

```
footerStyle= new Style();
footerStyle.setHorizontalAlign(HorizontalAlign.RIGHT);
```